# How to send my Database in SQL server management Studio 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

Hello I am new to Database, How can I share the Database ,its tables along with inserted data that I created using Diagrams. Is there any way I can copy the whole SQL code send it to my project members so they can run it or Is there any other way to send all files/folders of my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Right click your database --> Tasks -->Generate scripts --> Select Tables/Stored procedures --> Advanced --> Types of data to script --> Select Schema and Data (option)
```

Comment: Thanks alot ..Will this also transfer my data and diagram?

Comment: It should transfer all your database schema/Data.

Comment: Sorry I am new to all these terms by schema you mean info about its structure like foreign key or primary key or it  mean it will also transfer my entered records.... :( Sorry for asking stupid things in advance.

Comment: Yes, everything.